# Php crop time from date time string

Tags: php

I have a *datetime* string which I would like to crop the 'time' part out of.
I need to do some calculation on it so I need to convert it to Unix time stamp.

What I've tried:

Use `substr`, and then `strtotime`, but when checking the result back to a human readable time format, it is not the same as the original date.

```
function convert($dbTime){
  $createDate = new DateTime($dbTime);
   $strip = $createDate->format('Y-m-d');
  $yearMonthDateArray = explode("-", $strip);
 }
```

The explode here crashes.

Edit: 
This is the value of dbTime: "2014-07-27 12:06:00" 
I want it to be "2014-07-27", and then have *strototime* on this format. This does not work. Converting it back to human readable date it generates 2014-07-06
Regarding comments: 
I have tried all sorts of `datetime` functions. They either crash or they don't return the proper time
Explode crashes - it doesn't continue to the next line of code.

Edit2: 
This is what's going on next. This returns false

```
$timeWithMakeTime = mktime(0,0,0,(int)$yearMonthDateArray[0], (int)$yearMonthDateArray[1],(int)$yearMonthDateArray[2]);
```

Comment: Cannot see any problem with this code: http://3v4l.org/ugAeK#v520 It works fine for what it does. As for *"Explode crashes - it doesn't continue to the next line of code"* - well, there's is no "next line of code" here. Please produce an actual running example that demonstrates an actual problem.

Comment: Thanks for your input. My code is currently a mish-mash of attempts. Reconstructing it proves difficult so I left out the 'return statement' as I don't even reach it.  Something strange happens, now it does continue. I've added another attempt in edit.

Comment: What is your actual goal with this? You want a UNIX timestamp for **midnight** that day? You want to "overwrite" any time component with `00:00:00`?

Comment: Exactly! The base goal is to calculate number of business days and I don't care for hours, minutes or seconds. I've got a code that uses timestamp for it. I'm using this: http://www.onlineconversion.com/unix_time.htm for comparison.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Discarding all your messy code, I assume you just want this:

```
$dbTime = '2014-07-27 12:06:00';
$date = new DateTime($dbTime);
$date->setTime(0, 0, 0);
echo $date->getTimestamp();
```

Comment: So I've reached this result with massive workarounds. It appears the  the bug is with the online converter, I dunno. Your trick is much faster. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

DateTime is an object, so what if you want to get timestamp you can do is as follows:

```
function convert($dbTime){
    $createDate = new DateTime($dbTime);
    return $createDate->getTimestamp();
}
```

You can read more about [getTimestamp](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.gettimestamp.php) and other [DateTime functions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php)

Make sure your variable $dbTime is in correct format. For example DateTime does not support split seconds.

Comment: Please read the question thoroughly. I'm not looking to make it a timestamp just as it is. Gotta give me some credit. See the added comments

Comment: even after your edit I still struggle to understand what you are after. Please read the documentation on DateTime, especially on the __construct function which is relevant for you here. Passing $dbTime with time into an object of DateTime doesn't make any difference. What are you looking to get in the end of it? a timestamp? A timestamp of "2014-07-27 12:06:00" or something else?

Answer (score 0):

```
$date = date('H:i:s', strtotime($dbTime));
echo $date;
```